# MongoDB not starting: Unable to create/open lock file No space left on device Is a mongod instance already running

Tags: linux, mongodb

MongoDB was already running for a couple of months then stopped suddenly.

I ran:

```
service mongod restart 
Restarting mongod (via systemctl):  Job for mongod.service failed because
the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" 
and "journalctl -xe" for details
```

then:

```
systemctl status mongod.service
mongod.service - SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-12-21 14:57:30 EST; 9s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 22675 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 28515 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database....
mongod[28515]: Error starting mongod. /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid exists.
systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

i checked the mongodb.log and got these:

```
I CONTROL  ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=24312 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongo 64-bit host=server-11
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.15
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: b8ff507269c382bc100fc52f75f48d54cd42ec3b
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { fork: true, pidFilePath: "/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid" }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongo", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock errno:28 No space left on device Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

which is weird because running `df -h` shows I still have a lot of space:

```
[root@server-11 /]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       20G  4.4G   15G  24% /
devtmpfs        485M     0  485M   0% /dev
tmpfs           494M     0  494M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           494M   57M  438M  12% /run
tmpfs           494M     0  494M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/0

[root@server-11 /]# df -i
Filesystem      Inodes IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1     1310720 68253 1242467    6% /
devtmpfs        123983   303  123680    1% /dev
tmpfs           126358     1  126357    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           126358   495  125863    1% /run
tmpfs           126358    16  126342    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           126358     1  126357    1% /run/user/0
```

i also ran ls -la /var/lib/mongo

```
total 376860
drwxr-xr-x.  3 mongod mongod      4096 Dec 21 16:18 .
drwxr-xr-x. 38 root   root        4096 Aug 17 13:25 ..
-rw-------.  1 mongod mongod  67108864 Aug 17 14:23 admin.0
-rw-------.  1 mongod mongod  16777216 Aug 17 14:23 admin.ns
drwxr-xr-x.  2 mongod mongod      4096 Dec 14 14:28 journal
-rw-------.  1 mongod mongod  67108864 Dec 20 16:59 learning_locker.0
-rw-------.  1 mongod mongod 134217728 Dec 20 16:59 learning_locker.1
-rw-------.  1 mongod mongod  16777216 Dec 20 16:59 learning_locker.ns
-rw-------.  1 mongod mongod  67108864 Dec 14 14:26 local.0
-rw-------.  1 mongod mongod  16777216 Dec 14 14:26 local.ns
-rw-r--r--.  1 mongod mongod        69 Aug 17 13:29 storage.bson
```

I installed mongodb with the root user and have been restarting mongo with the same user. Im not sure why it would change all of a sudden.

Comment: Does mongo user still has writing permission on `/var/lib/mongo/`?

Comment: +1 from me for an excellent first question: it's clear you've already put some thought into the problem, you've shown us what you did and what you got, and you've done a good job of formatting it.  I hope you get an answer that works for you (don't forget to accept it, if you do) and you decide to stay around.

Comment: I created only one user with db.createUser({user:"username",pwd:"password",roles:["readWrite"]}). Was that the writing permission you were talking about? I'm sorry I'm really new to this I'm not sure if I am answering your question. Or by mongo user you meant server user? Would it help if I set /var/lib/mongo with a 777 permission?

Answer (score 2):

More often than not, this error message is misleading. As you saw, the disk space is not the problem.

If `mongod` failed and died before clearing the lockfile (`/var/lib/mongo/mongod.lock`), the lockfile is still there, the new instance will not be able to create a new lockfile and will die with this error message.

To restart `mongod`, first make sure no `mongod` instance is running, delete the lockfile, and start it.

Other cause for this message is when you started mongod with one user (e.g. `mongod`) and tried to start it again under another user (`www-data` or `nobody`). In this case, the user `www-data` will not have permission to write on the lock directory. If you run `ls -la /var/lib/mongo` you can see which user is owner of the directory and if you are starting `mongod` with the correct user.

Comment: Yes, there were no other instance of mongo running and mongod.lock was present. What i did was:                                                                                          1. Delete the .lock file                                                                                             2. Restart mongo but still the same result, but there was no other entry in /var/log/mongodb regarding a error.

Comment: I edited my original post to add the output of `ls -la /var/lib/mongo`.. I also read something about OpenVZ host having the problem and not the VPS. I'm not sure if it has something to do with this scenario

Answer (score -2):

sudo restorecon -R /var/lib/mongo

I had no problem with the disk or permissions. I researched and finally came across that tidbit. It works every time I have that issue. Every time you change that directory (link or whatever) it has to be run. jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-4170

Comment: What makes you believe it's SELinux problem? The error messages suggest it's a disk space issue... I suggest you provide more reasoning for your answer.

Comment: I had no problem with the disk or permissions.  I researched and finally came across that tidbit.  It works every time I have that issue.  Every time you change that directory (link or whatever) it has to be run.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-4170